# How to store timestamp message from aws iot button to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I am sending message from my AWS iot button and storing it to the DynamoDB. My partition key is "SerialNumber" and the sort key is "ClickType". The message is stored according to the key. But it is overwriting the previous data if there is already same ClickType. I do not want to overwrite my previous data and also want to see the time of the sending message. Can somebody provide me any suggestion or any link about how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your AWS IoT rule for getting the message to lambda has the timestamp when the message was captured by Aws Iot rules engine. You could catch that on your rule and store on your Dynamodb table.
To do that, you have to use the [timestamp() function from AWs IoT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-function-timestamp)

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the timestamp using the timestamp() function. But I want to see more than one data for "Single" or "Double" click. Right now, it is just overwriting the previous "Single" or "Double" click data. As a result, I have 3 types data based on "Single", "Double" and "Long" click. My partition key is "SerialNumber" and the sort key is "ClickType". Do I need to remove the sort key?  @dvd86

Comment: Oh I see, now I understood. In that case, I would remove the sort key and work with global secondary indexes.